# Reposition an embedded Facebook video?

Tags: html, css, embedded-video, video-embedding

Sorry if this is a bit obvious, I'm just beginning with HTML. I have embedded a Facebook video on to my website, and I'm able to adjust the width, height, etc. However, I cannot reposition it. Align center doesn't work, but align right does. I want to position it in percentages (e.g. top: 20%;, left: 20%) I tried putting the embed code in a div and using CSS to give it the positions, but it didn't do anything. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<div class="video1">
   <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F1255124634539700%2Fvideos%2F1623012424417584%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video1{
    top: 30%
    left: 35%;
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

```
<style type="text/css"> .video1 {display: flex; justify-content: center;} </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to center it then try to change your css to this one ,its working

```
<style type="text/css">

.video1{
    margin:auto;
    width:560px;    
}

</style>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me? It still displays the video in the top left corner of the page.

Comment: make sure the width  is same width of your embedded fb video

Comment: My apologies. Made a stupid mistake in my CSS and missed a semi-colon.  Sorry. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, no problem